# How to add struct properties dynamically to avoid redundancy code?

Tags: json, go, struct, initialization

Hi I'm basically struggling to avoid redundancy in my Code.

Here is my Struct:

```
type Person struct {
    Name   string
    Text   string
    Status string
}
```

Here is my Func:

```
func ReworkElementsFromClient(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    var persons []Person
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&persons)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    if len(persons) == 0 {
        err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(persons)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
        return
    }

    persons = append([]Person{persons[0]}, persons...)
    persons = persons[:len(persons)-1]

//Trying to avoid redundancy here 
    persons[0].Name = CreateRandomChars(CreateRandomNumbers(8, 16))
    persons[0].Text = CreateRandomChars(CreateRandomNumbers(8, 16))
    persons[0].Status = CreateRandomChars(CreateRandomNumbers(8, 16))

    err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(persons)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    return
    }
```

How to avoid calling each properties at `Person[0]` to randomizing them?

Comment: Do you want people to improve your code? I'm a little confused.

Comment: It will take more than 2 lines to remove those 2 similar looking lines. What do you want exactly?

Comment: 3 lines of "redundancy" isn't worth eliminating. You'll make your code harder to read.

Comment: It's about as optimized as it can be. Reducing the rework necessary when adding a field means using reflection which will be slower, i.e. de-optimizing.

Comment: @Flimzy now instead of 3 lines think about 100

Comment: If the 100 lines are that simple, just use 100 lines (I'd move them into a stand-alone function, say `SetRandomValues(person)` or something, to leave your code flow more readable).  "Redundancy" in this case, is both _faster_ and _more readable_ than the alternative.

Comment: This would likely be better received as a question on Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without touching reflection, the following code is cleaner and shorter, yet identical to what your code is doing, and can be easily extended for new fields:

```
c := func() string { return CreateRandomChars(CreateRandomNumbers(8, 16)) }

p := persons[0]
p.Name = c()
p.Text = c()
p.Status = c()

persons = append([]Person{p}, persons[:len(persons)-1]...)
```

Although I don't really understand why you're duplicating the first slice element and dropping the last. More logical would be to just alter the first element and not drop the last.

A slightly modified version where the utility takes a `string` pointer could look like this:

```
c := func(s *string) { *s = CreateRandomChars(CreateRandomNumbers(8, 16)) }

p := persons[0]
c(&p.Name)
c(&p.Text)
c(&p.Status)

persons = append([]Person{p}, persons[:len(persons)-1]...)
```

This pointer version can also be simplified further if the number of fields grows, as you can pass them using a `for` loop:

```
c := func(s *string) { *s = CreateRandomChars(CreateRandomNumbers(8, 16)) }

p := persons[0]
for _, s := range []*string{&p.Name, &p.Text, &p.Status} {
    c(s)
}

persons = append([]Person{p}, persons[:len(persons)-1]...)
```

And now that we're referring to the `c()` function variable only once, we can even leave it out entirely:

```
p := persons[0]
for _, s := range []*string{&p.Name, &p.Text, &p.Status} {
    *s = CreateRandomChars(CreateRandomNumbers(8, 16))
}

persons = append([]Person{p}, persons[:len(persons)-1]...)
```